# Ruby code that doesn't work. How comes? I included Enumerable, implemented each but reject doesn't behave as I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this simple class

```
class FibSequence
    include Enumerable


    def initialize(num) 
        @sequence = fib(num)
    end

    def fib(n)
        vals = [1, 1]
        return [1] if n == 1
        return vals if n == 2

        (n-2).times do 
            vals.push(vals[-1] + vals[-2]) 
        end
        return vals
    end

    def each(&block)
        @sequence.each(&block)
    end

end
```

when I call it like this:

f = FibSequence.new(6)

f.reject { |s| s.odd? }

f.each { |s| print(s,':') }

I expect  => [2, 8]
but I get => 1:1:2:3:5:8:

Comment: Is there a typo in the 'calling' code?  It doesn't parse correctly for me, is the `f.reject...` statement supposed to be on it's own line?

Comment: it was a typo, I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) method does return the result as new array. You thus have to write

```
f = f.reject { |s| s.odd? }
```

.

Comment: as Jon M is pointing out, .delete_if is not available on Enumerable

Answer (score 0):

`reject` doesn't modify the original array, but returns a modified copy.  In your code the second statement returns an array with the odd entries removed, but you are discarding it, and then calling `.each` on the original unmodified array.  You would need to act on the modified array returned by `reject`:

```
f = FibSequence.new(6)
f.reject{|s| s.odd?}.each {|s| print(s,':')}
```

EDIT: Removed the option to use `reject!` as the question is based on an `Enumerable` not an `Array`.

Comment: reject! gives an undefined method exception

Comment: Ah I had mis-read your question, thought you were operating on an array, but it's actually an `Enumerable` in which case you can't modify the original collection with `reject!` or `delete_if`.